# Where do we see our deleted posts in the latest ui on My Android 11 device?

Tags: support, profile-page, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Previously,we could see our deleted posts like answers and questions in a particular place (at the bottom of our profile page). But, we find it nowhere in the latest ui. So, where are they now? Or they are removed permanently?
New user Interface
[image]

Comment: It's still in the same place, bottom of the questions/answers lists on the activity page

Comment: The [deleted-questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/deleted-questions/info) and [deleted-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/deleted-answers/info) tags here on Meta also have links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This are found in your user profile, under "Activity" and either on "Questions" or "Answers" respectively.

E.g. to find your deleted questions you [go to your profile and switch to the activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=topactivity), then you select "questions", and at the bottom of the listing you'll see a link to your "deleted questions":

> [image]

For your convenience, links to your:

- [Deleted Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/current)
- [Deleted Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-answers/current)

Comment: Thanks! I missed to include that I'm accessing SOF via my Android 11 device. But,  I find it using your answer.